# What is the Chinese Mythology Cinematic Universe?

Tags: movie-franchise, ne-zha

In posters such as the below, the theatrical release of "Ne Zha" (2019) was promoted in English-speaking markets as "a must-see in the Chinese Mythology Cinematic Universe". But what actually is the Chinese Mythology Cinematic Universe? Apart from Ne Zha, what other films does it contain?

[image: Ne Zha poster]

Comment: I think this is just a marketing trick since this movie is not connected with anything else. However there have been some other Chinese movies based on mythology popular lately, so this is what they could be referring to.

Comment: Is this an official poster? or somewhat fan art? Or, is it quoting something from critic and/or article written about it?

Comment: @Vishwa it's definitely an official poster and not fan-art. I saw this film yesterday at the Odeon Haymarket in London, and this poster was displayed outside the cinema advertising the film. This particular image was downloaded from the internet rather than from a photograph I took of the poster, but it's the same poster. The actual quote is not attributed as you can see from the poster, so I don't know whether it comes from a critic article, or from some company directly associated with the film or its distribution.

Answer (score 4):

Without any definitive answer, I can guess that it may be referring to a series of animated Chinese mythology movies produced by [Coloroom Pictures](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%9C%8D%E5%B0%94%E6%9E%9C%E6%96%AF%E5%BD%A9%E6%9D%A1%E5%B1%8B%E5%BD%B1%E4%B8%9A):

- [Monkey King: Hero is Back (2015)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_King:_Hero_Is_Back)
- [Big Fish & Begonia (2016)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Fish_%26_Begonia)
- [Ne Zha (2019)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ne_Zha_(2019_film))
- Master Jiang and the Six Kingdoms (2020)
- Phoenix (2020)
- Monkey King: Havoc in Heaven (2021)

The name is obviously intended to make people think of the Marvel Cinematic Universe. And in typical MCU fashion, the post-credits scene of *Ne Zha* also serves as a preview of the next film, *Master Jiang and the Six Kingdoms*.

Also, one of the two mid-credits scenes of *Ne Zha* heavily teases a (yet to be announced) sequel to the film.